# Lodash: deep compact or compact nested object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I would like to apply lodash compact method on all key/values of a nested object.
My array currently looks like this:

```
[{
    "_id": "5aa98490e0e1b4045a67f1d5",
    "name": "Lesson01-Page01 JP",
    "parentLesson": {
        "_id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce",
        "childPages": null
    },
    "background": null,
    "frontImage": null,
    "animation": null
},
{
    "_id": "5aa9a9c9175873221ca26d66",
    "name": "Lesson01-Page02 JP",
    "parentLesson": {
        "_id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce",
        "childPages": null
    },
    "background": null,
    "frontImage": null,
    "animation": null
}]
```

So basically I want lodash compact to return an array that would eliminate all key/values where value is null. Like this:

```
[{
    "_id": "5aa98490e0e1b4045a67f1d5",
    "type": "static01",
    "parentLesson": {
        "_id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce"
    }
},
{
    "_id": "5aa9a9c9175873221ca26d66",
    "name": "Lesson01-Page02 JP"
    "parentLesson": {
        "_id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce"
    }
}]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the weirdest thing I have done in Lodash to date, but this will work for any recursively-nested object structure, no matter the depth.

```js
const sampleInput = [
    {
        "_id": "5aa98490e0e1b4045a67f1d5",
        "type": "static01",
        "name": "Lesson01-Page01 JP",
        "createdAt": "2018-03-14T20:22:40.769Z",
        "parentLesson": {
            "_id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce",
            "region": "5aa98ce6c6752a0dcb60d3c6",
            "childPages": null,
            "id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce"
        },
        "background": null,
        "frontImage": null,
        "animation": null,
        "ballonImage": null,
        "image01": null,
        "image02": null,
        "image03": null,
        "image04": null,
        "imageDrop": null,
        "soundFile": null,
        "videoFile": null,
        "childBadges": null,
        "id": "5aa98490e0e1b4045a67f1d5"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5aa9a9c9175873221ca26d66",
        "name": "Lesson01-Page02 JP",
        "type": "static02",
        "createdAt": "2018-03-14T23:01:29.161Z",
        "parentLesson": {
            "_id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce",
            "region": "5aa98ce6c6752a0dcb60d3c6",
            "childPages": null,
            "id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce"
        },
        "background": null,
        "frontImage": null,
        "animation": null,
        "ballonImage": null,
        "image01": null,
        "image02": null,
        "image03": null,
        "image04": null,
        "imageDrop": null,
        "soundFile": null,
        "videoFile": null,
        "childBadges": null,
        "id": "5aa9a9c9175873221ca26d66"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5aaa81a01fadff49f70c9271",
        "name": "Lesson01-Page03 JP",
        "type": "static03",
        "createdAt": "2018-03-15T14:22:24.934Z",
        "parentLesson": {
            "_id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce",
            "region": "5aa98ce6c6752a0dcb60d3c6",
            "childPages": null,
            "id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce"
        },
        "background": null,
        "frontImage": null,
        "animation": null,
        "ballonImage": null,
        "image01": null,
        "image02": null,
        "image03": null,
        "image04": null,
        "imageDrop": null,
        "soundFile": null,
        "videoFile": null,
        "childBadges": null,
        "id": "5aaa81a01fadff49f70c9271"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ab384b46f91791a1a8e56f4",
        "name": "Lesson01-Page04 JP",
        "type": "interactive01",
        "createdAt": "2018-03-22T10:25:56.824Z",
        "parentLesson": {
            "_id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce",
            "region": "5aa98ce6c6752a0dcb60d3c6",
            "childPages": null,
            "id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce"
        },
        "background": null,
        "frontImage": null,
        "animation": null,
        "ballonImage": null,
        "image01": null,
        "image02": null,
        "image03": null,
        "image04": null,
        "imageDrop": null,
        "soundFile": null,
        "videoFile": null,
        "childBadges": null,
        "id": "5ab384b46f91791a1a8e56f4"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ab3872b5260f41ba7c480a4",
        "name": "Lesson01-Page05 JP",
        "type": "interactive02",
        "createdAt": "2018-03-22T10:36:27.387Z",
        "parentLesson": {
            "_id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce",
            "region": "5aa98ce6c6752a0dcb60d3c6",
            "childPages": null,
            "id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce"
        },
        "background": null,
        "frontImage": null,
        "animation": null,
        "ballonImage": null,
        "image01": null,
        "image02": null,
        "image03": null,
        "image04": null,
        "imageDrop": null,
        "soundFile": null,
        "videoFile": null,
        "childBadges": null,
        "id": "5ab3872b5260f41ba7c480a4"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ab387ce5260f41ba7c480ab",
        "name": "Lesson01-Page06 JP",
        "type": "interactive03",
        "createdAt": "2018-03-22T10:39:10.216Z",
        "parentLesson": {
            "_id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce",
            "region": "5aa98ce6c6752a0dcb60d3c6",
            "childPages": null,
            "id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce"
        },
        "background": null,
        "frontImage": null,
        "animation": null,
        "ballonImage": null,
        "image01": null,
        "image02": null,
        "image03": null,
        "image04": null,
        "imageDrop": null,
        "soundFile": null,
        "videoFile": null,
        "childBadges": null,
        "id": "5ab387ce5260f41ba7c480ab"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ab3883f5260f41ba7c480b6",
        "name": "Lesson01-Page07 JP",
        "type": "interactive04",
        "createdAt": "2018-03-22T10:41:03.958Z",
        "parentLesson": {
            "_id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce",
            "region": "5aa98ce6c6752a0dcb60d3c6",
            "childPages": null,
            "id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce"
        },
        "background": null,
        "frontImage": null,
        "animation": null,
        "ballonImage": null,
        "image01": null,
        "image02": null,
        "image03": null,
        "image04": null,
        "imageDrop": null,
        "soundFile": null,
        "videoFile": null,
        "childBadges": null,
        "id": "5ab3883f5260f41ba7c480b6"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ab388d25260f41ba7c480c5",
        "name": "Lesson01-Page08 JP",
        "type": "interactive05",
        "createdAt": "2018-03-22T10:43:30.048Z",
        "parentLesson": {
            "_id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce",
            "region": "5aa98ce6c6752a0dcb60d3c6",
            "childPages": null,
            "id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce"
        },
        "background": null,
        "frontImage": null,
        "animation": null,
        "ballonImage": null,
        "image01": null,
        "image02": null,
        "image03": null,
        "image04": null,
        "imageDrop": null,
        "soundFile": null,
        "videoFile": null,
        "childBadges": null,
        "id": "5ab388d25260f41ba7c480c5"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ab38b445260f41ba7c480ce",
        "name": "Lesson01-Page09 JP",
        "type": "interactive06",
        "createdAt": "2018-03-22T10:53:56.899Z",
        "parentLesson": {
            "_id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce",
            "region": "5aa98ce6c6752a0dcb60d3c6",
            "childPages": null,
            "id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce"
        },
        "background": null,
        "frontImage": null,
        "animation": null,
        "ballonImage": null,
        "image01": null,
        "image02": null,
        "image03": null,
        "image04": null,
        "imageDrop": null,
        "soundFile": null,
        "videoFile": null,
        "childBadges": null,
        "id": "5ab38b445260f41ba7c480ce"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ab38cbd5260f41ba7c480d5",
        "name": "Lesson01-Page10 JP",
        "type": "interactive07",
        "createdAt": "2018-03-22T11:00:13.599Z",
        "parentLesson": {
            "_id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce",
            "region": "5aa98ce6c6752a0dcb60d3c6",
            "childPages": null,
            "id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce"
        },
        "background": null,
        "frontImage": null,
        "animation": null,
        "ballonImage": null,
        "image01": null,
        "image02": null,
        "image03": null,
        "image04": null,
        "imageDrop": null,
        "soundFile": null,
        "videoFile": null,
        "childBadges": null,
        "id": "5ab38cbd5260f41ba7c480d5"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ab3914980099f2ad11da78b",
        "name": "Lesson01-Page11 JP",
        "type": "interactive08",
        "createdAt": "2018-03-22T11:19:37.762Z",
        "parentLesson": {
            "_id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce",
            "region": "5aa98ce6c6752a0dcb60d3c6",
            "childPages": null,
            "id": "5aa946f2e6d64f5180c8e7ce"
        },
        "background": null,
        "frontImage": null,
        "animation": null,
        "ballonImage": null,
        "image01": null,
        "image02": null,
        "image03": null,
        "image04": null,
        "imageDrop": null,
        "soundFile": null,
        "videoFile": null,
        "childBadges": null,
        "id": "5ab3914980099f2ad11da78b"
    }
];

// You need to create this mixin because it needs to be called recursively.
_.mixin({ compactObject: function(input) {
  return !_.isObject(input) ? input
    : _.chain(input)
      .keys()
      .filter(key => input[key])
      .map(key => ({
        [key]: _.isObject(input[key]) ? _.compactObject(input[key]) : input[key]
      }))
      .reduce(_.extend)
      .value();
}});

const newData = _.map(sampleInput, _.compactObject);

console.log(newData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Indeed, that does look super crazy. I can see you have a lodash Mastery here. It works fine in the Code Snipet, but on my server I got an error "Maximum call stack size exceeded". I am not sure if this is funny or scary since I should have stack enough to deal with much bigger objects than the one I have used.

Comment: @pedrosimao => Do you have an updated object structure that I could test against? This works for this specific dataset, but it might be encountering something that I am not handling.

Comment: Sure, here is the exact example I have used: https://drive.google.com/open?id=11j7uI3V6Gw2-TdPROtunvW_Iuqm8zZDn

Comment: @pedrosimao => I added your dataset from that file to my code above and it works perfectly. There must be something else in your code that is causing your stack overflow problem.